# How to connect Loopback API with mongdb port in Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, loopback, google-kubernetes-engine

I am following [this blog](http://blog.kubernetes.io/2017/01/running-mongodb-on-kubernetes-with-statefulsets.html) to deploy MongoDB in GKE and I came to a point where I need to connect my `Loopback-API` image in different pod but the same cluster to talk to the database.

Since the local development works as aspected with this `datasource.json` as following:

```
{
  "db": {
    "host": "database",
    "port": 27017,
    "url": "",
    "database": "test",
    "password": "",
    "name": "mongoDS",
    "user": "",
    "connector": "mongodb"
  }
}
```

In the tutorial, it is written that,
the connection string URI would be:

```
“mongodb://mongo-0.mongo,mongo-1.mongo,mongo-2.mongo:27017/dbname_?”
```

I am not sure how to implement it to the above `datasource.json`. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial creates a headless service with the name "mongo" in the default ns.

Replace your `"host": "database"` with `"host": "mongo"` in your pod's datasource.json.

Answer (score 0):

First, in Loopback's datasource, the name attribute is the same as the key of datasource. Second, the host attribute ought to be the name of pod that contains mongo DB.